# Python: Change Capitalization of a part of output file

Tags: python, filenames, capitalization

I'm trying to change a python script that is designed to detect the language of the text in a file. It detects the language & puts the language detected in ISO format at the end of the filename. Unfortunately it outputs the Lang code in all lowercase.

Now a few places in the script I found this `sub_lang = filename[-3].lower()` but unfortunately changing those to `.upper` does nothing to change the output.

All files will end in `.LAN.vtt` or `.ENG.srt` or `.123.ssa` with a 3 character extension as well as a 3 character LANGUAGE code. The script I'm editing has the ability to output either 3 character or 2 character ISO codes, but for my use I will always be using 3.

I thought this would be a simple change but everything I've found does not seem to work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered my error, I was arguing the wrong place.
There a line

```
def to_3_letter_lang(lang):
    try:
        return iso639.to_iso639_2(lang)
```

that when I added the `.upper()` it altered it as I wanted. I had thought since the earlier argument specified the `.lower()` it was the problem, but it was not

The context of this:

```
def to_2_letter_lang(lang):
    try:
        return iso639.to_iso639_1(lang).upper()
    except iso639.NonExistentLanguageError:
        return False


def to_3_letter_lang(lang):
    try:
        return iso639.to_iso639_2(lang).upper()
    except iso639.NonExistentLanguageError:
        return False
```

I'll not mark it as solved until tomorrow if anyone has any further information to add

So the answer is with the `.upper()` tag, it just needs to be attached to the correct field